# Prove $\sinh(u+v-\eta)\sinh(2v)-\sinh(\eta)\sinh(u-v) = \sinh(2v-\eta)\sinh(u+v)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

How to prove ?

$$\frac{\sinh(u+v-\eta)\sinh(2v)-\sinh(\eta)\sinh(u-v)}{\sinh(u+v)} = \sinh(2v-\eta)$$

Comment: Please show what work you have done towards this, and why you are stuck. This will help people give answers at your experience level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** use that
$$
\sinh z=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}
$$

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!